# Forcing responsive Bootstrap grid to not collapse in phone mode

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a site with Bootstrap. There are times when I want the grid to collapse in phone mode, but sometimes I don't - the top menu is a bar, for instance, which contains a couple of items in a row. And I want them to stay floated while in phone mode, not collapse on top of each other which is the default behavior for a ".row-fluid" grid.

Is there a built-in way of accomplishing this, like a non-responsive grid in all resolutions? Or will I have to roll my own?

Comment: So if they don't collapse they won't fit within the viewport width and you'll need to scroll, right?

Comment: No, it's a fluid row so the spans would just shrink.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but it comes up in a google search and I found the answer...

> Don't want your columns to simply stack in smaller devices? Use the extra small and medium device grid classes by adding .col-xs-* .col-md-* to your columns.

From here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed